# How can I positively identify a dog which was stolen from me 1.5 years ago?

Tags: dogs, identification

I am an amateur siberian laika dog breeder. A year and a half ago, one of my dogs, a female a West Siberian Laika, was abducted while I was away. A dog has been found that may be her, but I need to be able to look at the dog and identify her.

How will I be able to make a positive identification of a dog after 1.5 years? She has no sign whatsoever how to identify her. She was with a male dog and had pups with him, I still have the male dog and some of her pups, could that help?

I still need to figure it out a protocol where I could make a decision like this:

1) test1 Y/N

2) test2 Y/N

....

decision Y/N

It would be better that I could identify her in 20 minutes or so.

Any help or hint would be welcomed.

I told everybody I could identify her because of some secret mark, this was a lie to be sure they would not try to fool me with an other dog.

Also, I have no photo of her expect a bad quality photo where you can't see the motives and colors of the fur. I put no microchips and no tatoos as I never thought she may be abducted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do a DNA test. Get the DNA of the parent and test it against the alleged child and see if it matches.

You can google DNA test for dogs and there are lot of links. You can probably call your vet to ask and see where you can do this test that's closest to you.

If the other side declines a DNA test, then it's probably a good idea to not pursue this.

I think this is the only way to be 100% sure that it is your dog. Make sure no one has the parents' DNA but you or else the test could be faked as well.

Comment: this is an excellent suggestion, I think it is called dog paternity tests. They can process samples of father, mother and kid dogs and say if yes or not the samples they have are compatibles.

Comment: Just a technical comment: from actual information I get from internet and the vets, they can do tests between father and kid or between father. mother and kid but aparently not directly mother and kid. Anyway, I am in a position of providing both DNA samples of father and kid and so the DNA of the alledged mother can be tested in a configuration mother-father-kid ( or Dam,sire,Offspring as we talk about dogs ). If paternity is comfirmed this must be the mother, if not confirmed, this can't be the mother.And we're talking here about costs of 100 to 200 USD... extremely afordable!

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is something specific which proves she is the same dog -- specific details of scar or coat which wouldn't be likely to occur in any other dog, an implanted id transponder,  some extremely unusual trick which you taught her and the current owner doesn't know she knows -- and you can prove that, I don't think you stand a chance of convincing a court that she's your dog rather than a similar dog... and even if you do, the court may not agree that it's in everyone's best interest for you to reclaim her.

First step is to talk to your vet about whether there are ANY reliable proofs of identity. Note that x-rays would be a last resort, since it would be reasonable for her current human to decline to cooperate. Ditto blood test.

If you can't come up with a conclusive, clear, noninvasive test... my advice would be to focus on the fact that she's alive, in good health, and being well cared for. Which is much better than what could have happened.

Never mind the point that, as you've described it, you don't want to get into an argument with these guys. Even if you win you may lose.

I'm sorry, but I just don't see a better outcome than that as being very likely.